# How can I bold the sorted header in treeview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I bold the sorted header(only one column) ?
I can't find how to change the color only one of column header...
I tried to change the text but it doesn't work.

For example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZxLp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP0bl.png)

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, text=col+"(Sorted)")

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

root = Tk()
columns = ('name', 'age')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False))

treeview.insert('', END, values=("Alex", "34"))
treeview.insert('', END, values=("Viky", "30"))

treeview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Reading the docs, I cannot find `tkinter` talking about specific columns, just overall, also it should be `command=lambda col=col: treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False))`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a `Style` to your `ttk.widget`

first you need to create an Instance of the `ttk Style` Class e.g. like this:

```
style = ttk.Style()
```

and then you have multiple options:

you can either apply a set style to all widgets of that type, like that:

```
style.configure('Treeview.Heading', foreground = 'red')
```

or you can create your own 'sub-Styles' to apply that manually:

```
style.configure('custom.TLabel', foreground = 'red')
style.configure('other.TLabel', foreground = 'yellow')
```

which you than apply when creating the widget like:

```
myLabel = ttk.Label(parent, text = 'I have a custom Style', style = 'custom.TLabel')
label2 = ttk.Label(parent, text = 'I have a different Style', style = 'other.TLabel')
```

in your simple case with just one treeview widget you can just go with the first one which could look something like this:
(I left out your function and imported tkinter as tk)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
# create an instance of Style class
style = ttk.Style()

#we're configuring the style of all Treeview Headers to be written in red 
#with a "custom" font which we can then set bold
style.configure('Treeview.Heading', foreground = 'red', font = ('Calibri', 13,'bold'))

columns = ('name', 'age')
#since we applied our style to all ttk.Treeviews, we don't have to manually set it
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False))

treeview.insert('', tk.END, values=("Alex", "34"))
treeview.insert('', tk.END, values=("Viky", "30"))

treeview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

for more Information about styling your application check out this awesome [overview](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-theme-layer.html)

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I want to change only one column(sorted column). I attached a image @newb

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, didn't get that... you might be able to do something with Style.map(), can test that later... but then its probably easiest to dynamicly change an image in the header ... gonna take a deeper look at that later @Alex

Comment: Thanks. Wait for your response. I prefer change the color of sorted header(Only one colum header. not all) @newb

Comment: When can you help ? @newb

Comment: I think you've reached a Limitation of the Treeview widget with this, at least as far as my knowledge and research go.. I think there might be a workaround highlighting the columns cells itself, since in the "body" you can make use of tag's but I would need to take a look into that. Would you be interested in such a workaround ? or would you rather use a 3rd party library ? let me know @Alex

Comment: for example: [tkintertable](https://pypi.org/project/tkintertable/)

Comment: I don't know. Something to easy to use. I prefer to base on built-in library of python. What's the quick and easy solution ? @newb

Comment: the problem is, that values in treeview are tuples - in your example name and age and you can only add a tuple and not seperate those from each other, which would be needed to be able to change the appearance seperate from each other .. so no quick and easy solution, if you really need this functionality you could try the tkintertable module, or take a look into [PyQT]8https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) but I also can't guarantee you that there is a quick and easy solution with eather of those, sorry that I couldnt be of more help @Alex

Comment: How can I do it based on built-in python ? with tkinter ? @newb

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ttk.Style` could solve your problem. You can play with its values and variables. Firstly, create a `style` and specify it in actual `treeview`.

Here's the code:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 10,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings

treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings',style="mystyle.Treeview")
```

Don't forget to mark this as accepted answer if it helps you to solve your problems.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I want to change only one column(sorted column). I attached a image. @Kshitiz